# Cómo leer un archivo XML alojado en la memoria interna

Tags: android, xml

Bueno, gracias por vuestra sugerencia, voy a intentar explicarme mejor.

Estoy realizando un programa que lee un archivo xml remoto, ya he conseguido
que funcione pero ahora quiero realizar otro que acceda a un xml 
alojado en la memoria interna del dispositivo y no se exactamente como acceder 
a la memoria interna, os dejo el código del programa con lectura de xml remoto.

```
        try {
    url = new URL(" http://www.misitio.net/prueba.xml");
    leerxml();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}

private void leerxml() {
    XmlPullParserFactory factory;
    XmlPullParser xml;

    int evento;

. declaracion
            . de
            . más
            . variables

    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        xml=factory.newPullParser();

        // me refiero a modificar esta linea para acceder a un archivo local en vez de a una url, una vez leido supongo que el parseo será igual.
        xml.setInput(url.openStream(), "UTF-8");

        evento=xml.getEventType();

        while (evento != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

            switch (evento){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                .
                .
                .
```

Espero haberme explicado mejor.

Comment: Buenas Ciberdrac, ya que has estado haciendo pruebas puedes agregar parte del código donde has implementado lo que mencionas, Edita la pregunta agrega código es mi sugerencia, tal vez con el código si tienes alguna duda o error se te pueda orientar mejor para dar una mejor respuesta a lo que pregunta. Personalmente si necesitas abrir un archivo xml necesitas investigar sobre archivos en Android ademas de memoria interna y te confirmo si es posible cargar un archivo xml desde el emulador.

Comment: Bienvenido Ciberdrac, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es
 recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!